# Как узнать код оборудования в ubuntu?

Tags: linux, сеть, wifi

Мне нужно драйвер к `Wi-Fi` модему скачать (из среды `Ubuntu` на `Windows XP`). Как добраться к нему - пока не понимаю.

[скриншоты устройства и его параметры](http://rghost.ru/38913823/image.png)

Comment: Расставте запятые, ни чего не понятно. И определитесь какой модем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите$lspci -vvv

Answer (score 0):

wi-fi модем, скорее всего usb, поэтому используйте `lsusb`.

Comment: у меня в ноут встроенный wi-fi

Comment: Сайт производителя ноута должен помочь. И да lspci -vv